# ngb-tabset not styling correctly

Tags: angular5, ng-bootstrap

I have a angular 5 component that is using ngbootstrap and bootstrap 4 to display a tabset. The tabset does not style correctly.

I am using ngb elsewhere in the project and it seems to work fine elserwhere.

Here is my component template:

[image]

I'm importing ngbmodule into my sub module:

[image]

and I have it imported `forRoot()` in my app module:

[image]

I also made sure to add bootstrap.min.css to my angular-cli.json when troubleshooting (and made sure the file was there):

[image]

Yet, when I view my component, the `ngb-tabset` isn't rendering correctly at all: 
[image]

I have restarted `ng serve` many times and checked my console for errors (clean), I'm not sure what could be the issue, as our ngb modals and ngb date pickers have been working fine (and still are) :'(

Comment: Don't post images. Post code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: Valid point. I have some confidential code and I couldn't just copy & paste, didn't have time to clean up either. Turned out to be a typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my problem:

```
<ng-template ngbTabContend>
    <p> here's some content</p>
  </ng-template>
```

notice `Contend` instead of `Content`. D'oh!